# Store Excel file in JavaScript variable WITHOUT user upload

Tags: javascript, html, excel, file

I'm looking to display the contents of an excel spreadsheet on a page as a table, so someone without any software knowledge can update the excel sheet and see the table change on the website. All the tutorials seem to want a user to upload the file to display, but I just want it to display on page load.

I'm sure there's a simple way of doing this but I just can't quite connect the dots, and I don't have any experience of using file variables in Java or JavaScript which makes things harder.

Methods I have found so far are the following:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="file-upload">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var spreadsheetFile;
document
    .getElementById("file-upload")
    .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        spreadsheetFile = event.target.files[0];
    });
```

This gets the file to be stored in the `spreadsheetFile` variable which is what I'm after but it does it by taking an upload from the user, with a HTML tag. Can I get the file stored in this variable as soon as the page loads, without requiring an upload from the user?